# "no such host is known" in system.http hitting endpoint to web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have reformatted my computer, pulled my project and trying to hit an endpoint.

I have 2x web api's, one running on localhost:8071, one on localhost:8072.

Hitting 8071 builds and debugs just fine. Hitting the second web api on localhost:8072, I get no break point hitting at the endpoint!

After turning on exception settings I can see that ONLY with one of the API's, I am getting an exception like below.

The error I'm getting is "No such host is found" and it's in System.Private.CoreLib

[image]

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

Full exception:

```
-       [0] {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)} System.Exception {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException}
```

Other people I know have pulled the code and are having no issues loading up the web api and hitting endpoints.

A fresh install should have fixed it, so not sure why this is still happening.

I am running .NET core 2.1.

I have tried changing the ports to no avail. Also, all firewalls are turned off. Not sure why one of the web api projects can hit endpoints and other one won't.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be 8072 is set to https?

Comment: I'm a little unclear if your API is what you are testing (and the test code can't hit it) or if the client you are testing is hitting an API endpoint but can't see it.  So, to take a step back, I presume you are able to "see" these two endpoints via a browser?

Comment: @Neil - i have tried using https as well and this doesn't work.

Comment: @BrendanGreen both APIs have an http get endpoint. For the 8071 one, I can hit the endpoint just fine through the browser. The 8072 one says "connection was reset" when i navigate. If I turn on CLR exceptions, that's when I get the above exception message.

Comment: What's the full stack trace?  Please get the text out of the exception dialog that you have posted in the picture, and paste the full text into the question.

Comment: Added to original message, thanks.

Comment: Share us the startup.cs for 8072. Did you configure any custom middleware compring with asp.net core built-in template? Try to clone your project in a new folder place and test again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No custom middleware was involved at all. Even after another full format it didn't work.

Managed to resolve this by upgrading the project to .NET core 2.2 SDK.